# Filter events from my calendar gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, date, google-calendar-api

I use a script in order to extract events from my calendar. It worked well, but the last two months it extracts also from 24th of previous month

Where is it the error?

```
function listEvents_WebOriginal() {

  var today = new Date();
  var Calendar  =  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

  // filtro sul calendario
  // -- mese -1 => se filtro mese settembre scrivo --> from 2016,8,1 to 2016,9,1
  // da guida --> getEvents(startTime, endTime)  ' Fonte: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)
  var events = Calendar.getEvents(new Date(2017,11,01), new Date(2017,12,01));

  var eventarray = new Array(); // l'array che contiene un evento per riga
```

Comment: Months in new Date start at 0. You likely want `new Date(2017,10,1), new Date(2017,11,1)` if you want Nov 1st to Dec1st - be careful with leading 0s too. They may be read as Octal

Answer (score 0):

As Date works with months from 0 to 11, you have to extract 1 from each month when you create the Date object. Try to make it more general like this.

```
function listEvents_WebOriginal() {

  var today = new Date();
  var Calendar  =  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var month = 11;

  // filtro sul calendario
  // -- mese -1 => se filtro mese settembre scrivo --> from 2016,8,1 to 2016,9,1
  // da guida --> getEvents(startTime, endTime)  ' Fonte: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)
  var events = Calendar.getEvents(new Date(2017, month - 1,01), new Date(2017, month, 01));

  var eventarray = new Array(); // l'array che contiene un evento per riga
```